# Consulta Mysqli SUM não retorna com resultado

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer a soma de uma coluna utilizando o método SUM do mysqli. O problema é que minha consulta não retorna com resultados. Meu código é este:

```
   $sql = 'SELECT SUM(size) as soma, porta FROM `'
        .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `porta`=?';
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param('s', $file->porta);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result(
        $soma
    ); 

   $query->close();

   echo $soma;
```

O que pode estar errado? Lembrando que todas as outras consultas sem o uso do SUM() funcionam perfeitamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltou usar `fetch`:

```
$sql   = 'SELECT SUM(size) as soma, porta FROM `'.$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `porta`=?';
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('s', $file->porta);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($soma); 

if($query->fetch()){
    echo 'result is ' . $soma;
}
$query->close();
```

Comment: Realmente! Inserindo o $query->fetch() funcionou, mas eu também tive que mudar de "SUM(size) as soma, porta" para apenas "SUM(size) as soma" e acabou dando tudo certo.